# How to make the text inside the second column break to a new line after reaching the column's flex-basis

Tags: css, flexbox

How to make the text inside the second column break to a new line after reaching the column's flex-basis and why is the right column's width increasing anyway considering I've set flex-basis to 100px?

```css
.specific-image-flexbox {
    display: flex;
}
.specific-image-column {
    flex: 4;
    background-color: red;
}
.artwork-info-column {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-flexbox">
    <div class="specific-image-column">sssss</div>
    <div class="artwork-info-column">sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-basis` !=`width`

Comment: Plus you have to tell the text to break at break at some point. `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: Wanna post that as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: The answer to your second questions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276) ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cnmxfh01/)).

Comment: Like Paulie said, add word-break: break-all and remove flex: 1, since it has no effect because of the flex-grow: 0 later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help for you!

```css
.specific-image-flexbox { display: flex; }
.specific-image-column {
    flex: 4;
    background-color: red;
}
.artwork-info-column {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
    background-color: blue;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-flexbox">
    <div class="specific-image-column">sssss</div>
    <div class="artwork-info-column">sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
</div>
```